# Why can't display or plot graphs/charts in Mobaxterm terminal using python libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, mobaxterm

I'm trying to plot a graph having from a DataFrame, having two columns (date and values), I used "matplotlib", "gnuplot" and many other libraries but without getting any wanted result.

For example I'm using this simple code :

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [590,540,740,130,810,300,320,230,470,620,770,250]
Y = [32,36,39,52,61,72,77,75,68,57,48,48]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

But I keep getting this error message when using matplotlib and it's a authorisation problem :

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:10.0
```

Any help would be appreciated and I'm open to alternative propositions.